# Setting meta tag back to default, like it was never declared

Tags: php, html, meta

In order to get the correct screenWidth for mobiles, you have to set a meta tag, but the meta tag isn't necessary on desktops, and make the size of the web page all messed up. First, I check to see if the screenWidth of their device is less than 500px or not. If they are, I redirect them to mobile.php, and if they aren't, I let them stay on index.php. However, if I let them stay on index.php, I need to reset the meta tag name = "viewport" back to default, so like, it was never declared in the first place. How would I do that?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I'd add the HTML tag here.